# How to fix the display issue when the tab heading is long for the jquery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a jQuery UI tabs, the tab headings of the element keeps changing.

**WHAT IS THE ISSUE**

when the tab heading is long, The tabs wont display properly and the tab headings as well,

The example can be found here [Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vinayhms/7zbzfxh7/9/), It has an input to accept the tab heading to be updated, when we give some long text as `"TESTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT".`
The tabs will not display properly.

How to resolve this issue by displaying tabs properly in-spite of any width of the text.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"The tabs will not display properly."*..?  The result looks fine and as expected for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the following CSS to make the tabs a certain `(max-)width` and cut off titles with `...` if they get too long.

```
.ui-tabs-anchor {
   white-space: nowrap;
   max-width: 9em;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zbzfxh7/10/)